# Is my orbital sander fixable?

Tags: sander

I have a Bosch PSS230 orbital sander (1990's vintage I think) which has served me very well until yesterday when it made a nasty noise and some crud dropped out of the bottom. Having had a look at it it looks like the 'crud' was the remnants of some sort of cement/rubber flexible force transfer system between the spindle and the footplate (excuse me if these terms are wrong).

Just wondering if anyone here has had a similar problem, and whether there is a suitable material (silicone, acrylic...) with which I can rebuild it?

Thanks, Dan

[image: red arrow shows where the 'crud' came from]

Comment: A photo of the crud and the general condition of the bottom of the sander would work miracles clarifying your text.  :-)

Comment: Thanks wallyk, have added a photo. The 'crud' itself has departed, but it was in the form of whitish-grey powdery lumps - may have looked a bit different 20 years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've sorted this out now, and in case I mislead anyone else with this, there was NOT a broken down flexible linkage in there, it was just compacted sawdust as some have suggested. The problem was just a sticky bearing which I've now freed up and all is good.

Comment: If this is the correct answer, you can select it by clicking the check mark (even though it was your question).

Answer (score 1):

https://www.boschtools.com/us/en/service/replacement-parts/

Bosch may have a answer.

i have had lots of lock using PERMATEX Right Stuff. Silicone based, fast drying, strong and dependable.

Comment: Thanks KENG, I suppose that the substance needs to have a suitable modulus to damp out the oscillations at the right level. Is Permatex quite a stiff sort of substance? Have you used it for this specific purpose?